# Mailto hyperlink: How to SendAs / SendOnBehalfOf?

Tags: html, excel, mailto

I am trying to make a hyperlink (in excel) for email, but cannot find any options for 'sendAs'.

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:asdf@hotmail.com & subject='Hello asdf'")
```

Is there an option in mailto, for a '**send-as**' or '**send-on-behalf-of**'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that was never designed into mailto. Here's the RFC syntax: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068#section-2

The RFC does elude to an "In-Reply-" field, maybe you can use it to route responses.

```
"An interesting use of 'mailto' URIs occurs when browsing archives of
messages.  A link can be provided that allows replying to a message
and conserving threading information.  This is done by adding an
In-Reply-To header field containing the Message-ID of the message
where the link is added, for example:

<mailto:list@example.org?In-Reply-To=%3C3469A91.D10AF4C@example.com%3E>
```